# MySQL: return data with same categories and then add more random data if necessary

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables: one table that handles videos and another table that handles video categories. One video can have multiple categories and categories can be associated with multiple videos: therefore the video_category_join table

Like so:

**TABLE: video**
`--------------------`
video_id
title
description
duration
...

**TABLE: video_category**
`--------------------`
video_category_id
name

**TABLE: video_category_join**
`--------------------`
video_id
video_category_id

Given a video_id, i want to pick 20 videos that have the same category as the video_id.

I was able to do the query, like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.video_id, v.title, v.duration
FROM video_category_join vc
JOIN video_category_join vc2 ON vc2.video_category_id = vc.video_category_id AND vc2.video_id <> vc.video_id
JOIN video v ON v.video_id = vc2.video_id
WHERE vc.video_id = 5
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 20
```

So far so good.

My problem is the following: sometimes the result set returns less then 20 videos, so i want to be able to compensate by picking random videos until i get to 20 videos (the priority is always picking videos with the same category and, if necessary, random videos until i get to 20 videos)

How do i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write another query that returns 20 random videos that aren't in the same category. Put the two queries together in a `UNION`, then return 20 videos from that.

To make it prefer the ones with the same category, add a `preferred` column to the subqueries, and order by that.

```
SELECT video_id, title, duration
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT v.video_id, v.title, v.duration, 1 as preferred
    FROM video_category_join vc
    JOIN video_category_join vc2 ON vc2.video_category_id = vc.video_category_id AND vc2.video_id <> vc.video_id
    JOIN video v ON v.video_id = vc2.video_id
    WHERE vc.video_id = 5
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 20
)
UNION (
    SELECT DISTINCT v.video_id, v.title, v.duration, 2 AS preferred
    FROM video_category_join vc
    JOIN video_category_join vc2 ON vc2.video_category_id <> vc.video_category_id AND vc2.video_id <> vc.video_id
    JOIN video v ON v.video_id = vc2.video_id
    WHERE vc.video_id = 5
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 20
)
ORDER BY preferred
LIMIT 20
```